# s:form overflowing to next jsp after form submit

Tags: jsp, jquery-mobile, struts2

I have an `<s:form>` tag in the first jsp and when i submit the form via struts action and display another jsp, the form tag seems to have extended to the second jsp as well. (as observed in firebug). I have some elements with the same id in these jsps and clubbing them together this way gives me a lot of issues. Also, the `<head>` section of the second jsp is ignored.

This is the basic structure of page1.jsp :

```
<html>
<head>
    <%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/page1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <s:form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post" namespace="">
        <div data-role="page" id="firstPage">
            <div id="xyz" class = "xyz"></div>
            .....//other elements
        </div>
    </s:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        .... // do stuff and submit "form1" to process.action
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The basic structure of page2.jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/page2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div data-role="page" id="secondPage">
       <div id="xyz" class = "xyz"></div>
       .....//other elements
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML as seen in firebug :

```
<html>
<head>
    <%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/page1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="process.action">
      <div data-role="page" id="firstPage">
          <div id="xyz" class = "xyz"></div>
          .....//other elements
      </div>
      <div data-role="page" data-external-page="true" id="secondPage">
          <div id="xyz" class = "xyz"></div>
          .....//other elements
      </div>
  <form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      .... // do stuff and submit "form1" to process.action
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So this results in the same html form having 2 elements with id "xyz", and other ids that have the same value across the two jsps.
What am i doing wrong, or how do i prevent this?

EDIT : I see the `data-external-page="true"` added to div "secondPage" in the rendered html. I tried to explicitly set it to false in page2.jsp, but that dint work either.

Also, refreshing works. although the data needed to populate the page is not present on reloading, this particular problem goes away on reloading.

EDIT: struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="location" namespace="/location">
        <action name="start" class="StartAction">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/templates/location/page1.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="process" class="ProcessAction">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/templates/location/page2.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

ProcessAction.java:

```
public class ProcessAction{
    private String xyz;

    //other elements
    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public String process() {
       //get data from DB and set it to xyz and other elements, 
       //whose corresponding elements are in page2.jsp

       return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to be more explicit in your description: if you've submitted a form and the action is firing, it's a new request, and the first page is *gone*. You're either not telling us something about the JavaScript, or your theme, or...? Your HTML won't be valid if you're using the default theme, of course, you can't put arbitrary divs around table rows.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is related to your error, but it is definitely an error: `<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>` must be put before any HTML statement, even before the DTD, not inside the `<head/>` tag;

you should use the `action` property of your `<s:form/>` element too, instead of setting it to blank and then (I guess) setting it through javascript

Comment: i did that... i still have the same problem.

Comment: Can you post your Struts.xml and the relevant part of your Action ? This is weird

Comment: Added my struts.xml and action.
  
Also, refreshing works. although the data needed to populate the page is not present on reloading, this particular problem goes away on reloading.